# Django Image won't come through on template from image directory

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to get an image to come through in my Django Template.  Can anyone help?

Here is my Template code:

```
<img src={{myImage}}/>
```

Here is my view code:

```
def base_book(request):
    theBook = Book.objects.get(title__contains="django")
    theAuthors = Book.objects.get(id=2)
    myAuthors = theAuthors.authors.all()
    myImage = "{{STATIC_URL}}two_scoops_django.png"
    return render(request, 'base_book.html', {'book': theBook, 'author': myAuthors, 'myImage': myImage})
```

I have the image file "two_scoops_django.png" saved in an image directory on my file path in my settings like so:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templatesDir'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'imageDir'),
    )
```

I have tried several different combinations trying to get it to come through, but it hasn't worked yet.

```
Here is my URL pattern as well if it helps:
    # DB - generated URL
    url(r'^base_book/$', base_book),
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Comment: Can you inspect element with Firebug or something and see what's the actual html your template is rendering for the `img`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{{ STATIC_URL }}` stuff will only work in the template. You have to change your template to

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{myImage}}"/>
```

and you view code to

```
def base_book(request):
    (...)
    myImage = "two_scoops_django.png"
    return render(request, 'base_book.html', 
      {'book': theBook, 'author': myAuthors, 'myImage': myImage}
      )
```

Comment: +1 Basically, `{{STATIC_URL}}` is valid only for templates, and not views. In this case the url would have `{{STATIC_URL}}` as part of the path, without evaluating it.